# I want to install Java through the command line but I don't have sudo access.

Tags: java, path, installation, java-7

This is what I have already done:

```
prompt> wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u60-b19/jdk-7u60-linux-i586.tar.gz"
```

Then untar it:

```
prompt> tar xzf jdk-7u60-linux-i586.tar.gz?AuthParam=1404311550_7de85e3ec1ae4acea63f229d9bf50dbell
```

Rename it:

```
prompt> mv jdk-7u60-linux-i586.tar.gz?AuthParam=1404311550_7de85e3ec1ae4acea63f229d9bf50dbe jdk-7u60-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

How to I finish the install without sudo access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really have to install it.  You should be able to navigate into [your jdk folder]/bin and run ./javac -version.

So just add the bin folder to your path and set $JAVA_HOME and you're good to go.

Comment: how do I add the bin folder to my path and set $JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @QuinnLiu export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/jdk/bin"; export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/jdk"

You can add that to your bashrc or run it everytime you want to use java.